# What's the correct to modify VUE component via javascript?

Tags: vue.js

javascript

```
(function(exports){

Vue.component('my-component',{
    props: {
        name: String
    },
    template: '<div>\
    <h1>name: {{name}}</h1>\
    </div>\
    '
});

var myApp = new Vue({
    el: '#myApp'
});

exports.app = myApp;
});
```

html

```
<div id="myApp">
        <my-component name="yo!" ref="test"></my-component>
</div>
```

console or javascript to access component

```
app.$refs.test.name = "yo man";
```

Then console display Vue Warning as following.
What's the correct to modify VUE component via javascript?

**[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name" 
(found in component )**

Answer (score 2):

What you should be doing is binding the name directive to a variable in the parent app.

```
(function(exports){

    Vue.component(
        'my-component',
        {
            props: {
                name: String
            },
            template: '<div><h1>name: {{name}}</h1></div>'
        }
    );

    var myApp = new Vue(
        {
            el: '#myApp',
            data: {
                name: "Yo!"
            }
        }
    );

    exports.app = myApp;
    }
))();
```

And your HTML

```
<div id="myApp">
    <my-component v-bind:name="name" ref="test"></my-component>
    <button v-on:click="name = 'Yo man'">Change</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxpoc69o/)