# Avoid mutating a prop directly in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

First of all, I am just starting playing with VueJS, so this cannot be a VueJS version thing as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215773/getting-avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be-overwritten-whene)

It might be a duplicate of :

- [How to solve [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten on vue.js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522266/how-to-solve-vue-warn-avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be) - the difference is that I am only trying to set the values with `v-bind`, once.
- [Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574661/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be-overwritten) - This also looks somehow similar, but the solution didn't worked for me.
- [What's the correct to modify VUE component via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311459/whats-the-correct-to-modify-vue-component-via-javascript) - this solution looks pretty much what I have in my case
- [vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component)

My problem starts with my Html looking like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <birthday-controls
       :birthDay="birthDay"
       :birthMonth="birthMonth"
       :birthYear="birthYear">
      </birthday-controls>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
Vue.component('birthday-controls', {

    template: `<div class="birthday">
    <input type="text" name="year"  placeholder="yyyy" v-model="birthYear" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm" v-show="validYear" v-model="birthMonth" size="3" maxlength="2"/>
    <input type="text" v-show="validYear && validMonth" name="day" placeholder="dd" v-model="birthDay" size="2" maxlength="2"/>
  </div>`,

    props: ['birthDay', 'birthMonth', 'birthYear'],

    computed: {
        validYear: function() {
            return (this.birthYear > new Date().getFullYear()-100 && this.birthYear < new Date().getFullYear()-14)
        },
        validMonth: function() {
            return (this.birthMonth > 0 && this.birthMonth <= 12)
        },
        validDay: function() {
            return (this.birthDay > 0 && this.birthDay <=31) //I have to add more checking here for february, leap years and ....
        }
    }

});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: function() {
        return {
            birthDay: "",
            birthMonth: "",
            birthYear: ""
        }
    },

});
```

I have prepared codepen here: http://codepen.io/AngelinCalu/pen/OpXBay

However, the second answer from here: [vuejs update parent data from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915436/vuejs-update-parent-data-from-child-component) makes me realise that I'm missing something

In that example it sets an `this.$emit('increment')` inside one of the methods, and triggers that on specific event.

In this other example: [Update a child's data component to the father component in vue.js using .vue webpack(vue2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895674/update-a-childs-data-component-to-the-father-component-in-vue-js-using-vue-web) , the answer suggest adding a `watch` to emit the change.

```
  watch: {
    val() {
      this.$emit('title-updated', this.val);
    }
  }
```

Now I'm even more confused! What is the right (or best) way to deal with this problem?

Note:
If I remove from the initial `html` :

```
   :birthDay="birthDay"
   :birthMonth="birthMonth"
   :birthYear="birthYear"
```

It still works as expected, but I'm still getting that Vue warn, however, if I'm following the method from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901150/2012740, it stops working, but I'm getting no error.

My Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/angelin8r/647m7vdf/

To conclude: I need the functionality from the beginning but without the `[Vue warn]`

This is what I got in my initial example:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "birthYear"

Comment: Do you need birthYear, birthMonth, or birthDay to be changed outside the component? As in, when it changes in the component, something outside the component knows?

Comment: Actually, I only need to change them inside the component. Probably I will store them into the DB somehow inside the `birthday-controls` component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is the result of setting `v-model` to the value of your properties. The reason is because if you change birthYear, birthMonth, or birthDay *outside* the component, then whatever the value is currently *inside* the component will be immediately overwritten.

Instead, capture a copy.

```
Vue.component('birthday-controls', {

    template: `<div class="birthday">
    <input type="text" name="year"  placeholder="yyyy" v-model="internalBirthYear" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm" v-show="validYear" v-model="internalBirthMonth" size="3" maxlength="2"/>
    <input type="text" v-show="validYear && validMonth" name="day" placeholder="dd" v-model="internalBirthDay" size="2" maxlength="2"/>
  </div>`,

    props: ['birthDay', 'birthMonth', 'birthYear'],

    data(){
      return {
        internalBirthDay: this.birthDay,
        internalBirthMonth: this.birthMonth, 
        internalBirthYear: this.birthYear
      }
    },

    computed: {
        validYear: function() {
            return (this.internalBirthYear > new Date().getFullYear()-100 && this.internalBirthYear < new Date().getFullYear()-14)
        },
        validMonth: function() {
            return (this.internalBirthMonth > 0 && this.internalBirthMonth <= 12)
        },
        validDay: function() {
            return (this.internalBirthDay > 0 && this.internalBirthDay <=31) //I have to add more checking here for february, leap years and ....
        }
    }

});
```

You did this almost exactly in your fiddle, but you did not correct your computed values.

```
computed: {
    validYear: function() {
        return (this.birthYear > new Date().getFullYear()-100 && this.birthYear < new Date().getFullYear()-14)
    },
    validMonth: function() {
        return (this.birthMonth > 0 && this.birthMonth <= 12)
    },
    validDay: function() {
        return (this.birthDay > 0 && this.birthDay <=31) //I have to add more checking here for february, leap years and stuff
    }
},
```

should be

```
computed: {
    validYear: function() {
        return (this.var_birthYear > new Date().getFullYear()-100 && this.var_birthYear < new Date().getFullYear()-14)
    },
    validMonth: function() {
        return (this.var_birthMonth > 0 && this.var_birthMonth <= 12)
    },
    validDay: function() {
        return (this.var_birthDay > 0 && this.var_birthDay <=31) //I have to add more checking here for february, leap years and stuff
    }
},
```

Comment: How is this different than what I have tried? I just named the variables differently.

Comment: @AngelinCalu If you do not need the value outside the component, there is no need to $emit. Otherwise, your fiddle looks fine except you didn't fix your computed values.

Comment: In this case, does it mean that I don't have to initialise them in the `new Vue()`, `data`, and declare them as `props` ?

Comment: @AngelinCalu I don't know where they initially come from. If you only set and save them in the component, there is no reason to pass them in I imagine.

Comment: so actually, my mistakes were in the computed methods for verification. But why if `this.var_birthDay = this.birthDay,`,    `return (this.var_birthDay > 0 && this.var_birthDay <=31)` is not the same with `return (this.birthDay > 0 && this.birthDay <=31)` . I don't get that.

Comment: The reason for the warning is that birthDay was a prop. Because birthDay is a prop, it can be changed from *outside* the component. That means that anything you do *inside* the component can be overwritten. If you move birthDay from props to data, and don't use props at all, then it doesn't matter if you call it birthDay or var_birthDay. You only introduce var_birthDay when you also have birthDay as a prop.

Comment: @AngelinCalu Look at this pen. The first component, if you change the text and click the button, the text will remain the same. The second component, if you change the text and click the button, the text will be overwritten because it uses a prop. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KWMjbx?editors=1011

Comment: Perfect example! Best way to see the difference! But what should we do with `vueMessage` ? It doesn't update in either one of the examples (between square brackets) http://codepen.io/AngelinCalu/pen/XMjXdr?editors=1011

Comment: Props are one-way. vueMessage is defined in the parent, so it will not change (for any primitive value). This is where $emit comes in. If you want to change the parent based on something in the child, you need to $emit an event and handle it in the parent. Think of a prop as an argument to a function in javascript. You can pass it in, and you can change it inside your function, but it will not change outside your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137375/discussion-between-angelin-calu-and-bert-evans).